# Speed Distance Time(RACES)

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

PLEASE GIVE THE DETAILED SOLUTION.

Tom, Jerry and Snoopy participate in a race. Tom covers the same distance in $49$ steps as Jerry covers in $50$ steps and Snoopy in $51$ steps. Tom takes $10$ steps in the same time as Jerry takes $9$ steps and Snoopy in $8$ steps. Who is the winner in the race?

Comment: This is not a homework-solving site. Share your attempts, being careful to specify the mathematical issue.

Answer (score 2):

Tom has longer steps and takes them faster, so you don't need to compute anything.